# How can I insert a scalar value and a binary value to a layer (last layer) in keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to modify the [network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.05225) which is implemented [here](https://github.com/brucechou1983/CheXNet-Keras). This network uses chest x ray [images](https://www.nih.gov/news-events/news-releases/nih-clinical-center-provides-one-largest-publicly-available-chest-x-ray-datasets-scientific-community) as input and classifies it into 14 categories (13 types of diseases and no finding). The network does not take the patient age and gender as an input. So I want to provide the network with that information too. In short At the last 3 layers of the network is like the following:

```
bn (BatchNormalization)         (None, 7, 7, 1024)   4096        conv5_block16_concat[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
avg_pool (GlobalAveragePooling2 (None, 1024)         0           bn[0][0]                         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
predictions (Dense)             (None, 14)           14350       avg_pool[0][0]
```

So what I have done so far is the following:
I simply pop the last dense layer using `model_vgg16.layers.pop()`.

Then as expexted the network turns into:

```
bn (BatchNormalization)         (None, 7, 7, 1024)   4096        conv5_block16_concat[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
avg_pool (GlobalAveragePooling2 (None, 1024)         0           bn[0][0]
```

I know that I can add a layer using:

```
new_layer = Dense(14, activation='softmax', name='my_dense')

inp = model.input
out = new_layer(model.layers[-1].output)

model2 = Model(inp, out)
```

But I do not know how to add a layer that takes the inputs from previous layer together with 1 scalar value (age [0:100]), and one binary value gender [0:1].

So **How can I add a last layer that takes inputs from previous layer together with 1 scalar value and 1 binary value?**

Edit: The base model I am using is DenseNet121. The some final layers looks like this:[image: DenseNet121 some of the last layers]

**EDIT**
The way I load the model is the following:

```
cp = ConfigParser()
cp.read(config_file)

# default config
output_dir = cp["DEFAULT"].get("output_dir")
base_model_name = cp["DEFAULT"].get("base_model_name")
class_names = cp["DEFAULT"].get("class_names").split(",")
image_source_dir = cp["DEFAULT"].get("image_source_dir")
image_dimension = cp["TRAIN"].getint("image_dimension")

output_weights_name = cp["TRAIN"].get("output_weights_name")
weights_path = os.path.join(output_dir, output_weights_name)
best_weights_path = os.path.join(output_dir, f"best_{output_weights_name}")
model_weights_path = best_weights_path

model_factory = ModelFactory()
model = model_factory.get_model(
    class_names,
    model_name=base_model_name,
    use_base_weights=False,
    weights_path=model_weights_path)
```

Now the model is in variable `model`.
Then as suggested I do

```
x = model.output
flat1 = Flatten()(x)
```

and get this error:

*ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_27: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2*

When I repeat the same thing after removing the last layer using `model.layers.pop()`

I still get the same error? Even though I have spent couple of hours cannot overcome that problem. So how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved by first removing the last layer (prediction layer) by

`model_original.layers.pop()`

Then defining another model which is the replica of the original model except the last layer

`model2 = keras.Model(model_original.input, model_original.layers[-1].output)`

after that the input, which includes the age is defined

`age = layers.Input(shape=(1,))`

Next, age input and the last layer of the previously defined network is concatenated using

`x = model2.output
concatenated = layers.concatenate([x, age])`

In th final step, a prediction layer is added after the concatenation to complete the network

`output = Dense(14, activation='linear')(concatenated)
model3 = keras.Model(inputs=[model_original.input, age], outputs=output)`

So the final layers of the design looks like that:
[image: final design]

Answer (score 1):

You can have a multi input model.

So instead of just using [this](https://github.com/brucechou1983/CheXNet-Keras/blob/master/models/keras.py#L79:L89):

```
img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)

base_model = base_model_class(
    include_top=False,
    input_tensor=img_input,
    input_shape=input_shape,
    weights=base_weights,
    pooling="avg")
x = base_model.output
predictions = Dense(len(class_names), activation="sigmoid", name="predictions")(x)
model = Model(inputs=img_input, outputs=predictions)
```

I am not sure what your **base_model** looks like there. BUT for the sake of it check the following, where the first input is imaginary and the shape of the second input should be the shape of your `age_gender_df.values`:

```
input1 = Input(shape=(64,64,1))
conv11 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(input1)
pool11 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv11)
conv12 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(pool11)
pool12 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv12)
flat1 = Flatten()(pool12)
# INSTEAD OF THE ABOVE INPUT I WROTE YOU CAN USE YOUR BASE MODEL

input2 = Input(shape=(2,2)) # HERE THIS SHOULD BE THE SHAPE OF YOUR AGE/GENDER DF
layer = Dense(10, activation='relu')(input2)
flat2 = Flatten()(layer)

merge = concatenate([flat1, flat2])
# interpretation model
hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(merge)
hidden2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(hidden1)
output = Dense(14, activation='linear')(hidden2)
model = Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=output)
```

**Summary**

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_30 (InputLayer)           (None, 64, 64, 1)    0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_23 (Conv2D)              (None, 61, 61, 32)   544         input_30[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_23 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 30, 30, 32)   0           conv2d_23[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_24 (Conv2D)              (None, 27, 27, 16)   8208        max_pooling2d_23[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_31 (InputLayer)           (None, 2, 2)         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_24 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 13, 13, 16)   0           conv2d_24[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_38 (Dense)                (None, 2, 10)        30          input_31[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_23 (Flatten)            (None, 2704)         0           max_pooling2d_24[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_24 (Flatten)            (None, 20)           0           dense_38[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_9 (Concatenate)     (None, 2724)         0           flatten_23[0][0]                 
                                                                 flatten_24[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_39 (Dense)                (None, 10)           27250       concatenate_9[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_40 (Dense)                (None, 10)           110         dense_39[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_41 (Dense)                (None, 14)           154         dense_40[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 36,296
Trainable params: 36,296
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**Visualisation:**

[image]

**EDIT:**

In your case I suppose the model should look like the following:

```
img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)

base_model = base_model_class(
    include_top=False,
    input_tensor=img_input,
    input_shape=input_shape,
    weights=base_weights,
    pooling="avg")
x = base_model.output
flat1 = Flatten()(x)

input2 = Input(shape=(2,2)) # HERE THIS SHOULD BE THE SHAPE OF YOUR AGE/GENDER DF
layer = Dense(10, activation='relu')(input2)
flat2 = Flatten()(layer)

merge = concatenate([flat1, flat2])
# interpretation model
hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(merge)
hidden2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(hidden1)
output = Dense(14, activation='linear')(hidden2)
model = Model(inputs=[img_input, input2], outputs=output)
```

Comment: The base model I am using is the DenseNet121. So I need to get rid of the last layer (prediction) layer and use the outputs of avg_pool layer as an input to a flattening layer. Then concatenate that branch with the branch coming from right hand side (Input_31, dense_38 and flatten_24) using a concatenate layer. As a result the final architecture will look like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-_F-8Za6-Vh3uveYFoG4JsAj6lq7ls5_) Did I understand correctly? Am I missing sth?

Comment: @ Vnc I use `new_layer = Flatten(input_shape=(None, 1024))

inp = model.input
out = new_layer(model.layers[-1].output)`  To add a flattening layer but when I do, I get this error: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_21: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2

Comment: How can i add a flattening layer after `avg_pool (GlobalAveragePooling2D (None, 1024)`

Comment: https://github.com/brucechou1983/CheXNet-Keras/blob/master/models/keras.py#L88 replace that with the flatten layer

Comment: [@VnC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5094841/vnc) Your solution seems optimal but I cannot overcome the error that is mentioned in the edit of the original post can you have a look at it please. Basically when I try to do ```x = model.output
flat1 = Flatten()(x)``` It gives me *ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_28: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2* (both when last layer is removed or not)

Comment: you'll need to check what is the shape of `model.output`. You can get that from the model summary. However, this error  basically suggests that there is a problem with the shape of your data -> it is something like `(x, y)` while it needs to be a tensor of shape `(x, y, z)`. If you are certain that the shape is correct and this layer still expects 3 dims instead of 2, there are ways in keras to expand dimensions (K.expand_dims) in order to match the expected dimensionality. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
from keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet121
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D,concatenate

input_image = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
# normalize age
input_age_and_gender = Input(shape=(2,))
base_model = DenseNet121(input_tensor=input_image, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
x = base_model.output
encoded_image = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
out = concatenate([encoded_image,input_age_and_gender])
output = Dense(14, activation='softmax')(out)
model = Model([input_image,input_age_and_gender],output)
```